# Read file .txt from res/raw and show it into list view

Tags: android, listview, file-io

I'm trying to read file `.txt` from *src/res/raw* folder and show it into `list view` in my android application.

Here is my code, previously im using static content to read data into `list view`.

```
String hewan[] = {"Beruang Madu", "Jerapah", "Gajah", "Beruang Kutub", "Harimau", "Kuda", "Kuda                 Nil", "Buaya", "Singa", "Beo", "Srigala"};

listAnimal = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_view);
search = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.search);
adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.animallist, R.id.product_name, hewan);
listAnimal.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there a good reason the text has to be from a file in the raw folder?

Android has good support for defining string arrays in XML.  Using string arrays also has the benefit of allowing you to localize your text if you want.

From Android's documentation on string resources:

You can define a string-array in your strings.xml file or another xml file in your res/values folder:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string-array name="planets_array">
        <item>Mercury</item>
        <item>Venus</item>
        <item>Earth</item>
        <item>Mars</item>
    </string-array>
</resources>
```

Then you can retrieve with:

```
Resources res = getResources();
String[] planets = res.getStringArray(R.array.planets_array);
```

More information can be found here:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html